# What is the closed form of this function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

It is well-known that the binomial coefficient has some monotonicity,
and that can be used to find the maximum and minimum of binomial coefficients.

Similarly, now let $\left(\delta_{i,j}\right)_{6\times6}$ be a binary
matrix with $\delta_{i,i}=1$ and $\delta_{i,j}=\delta_{j,i}=1$ or
$0$ when $i\ne j$ and $\delta_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{6}\delta_{i,j}$.
Let's define
$$
f(k):=\min_{\delta_{1}+\delta_{2}+\delta_{3}+\delta_{4}+\delta_{5}+\delta_{6}=2k}\delta_{1}\delta_{2}\delta_{3}\delta_{4}\delta_{5}\delta_{6}
$$
for integer $k$ , $3\le k\le18$, then what is the closed form or
combinatorial expression of $f(k)$ as a function of $k$?

Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my comment because there's something still unclear in your problem statement. For odd $k$, there is no matrix of the type you describe, because of the constraint $\delta_{i,j} = \delta_{j,i} $, if indeed that's what you want.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt  Thank you for your comment, and it has now been revised. Thanks.

Comment: Just so I understand the idea here — $\delta_{i,j}$ is just a symmetric (0,1) matrix with all diagonal entries 1? Or are there any other constraints?

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3559389/87355

Answer (score 2):

The minimum is achieved by filling as large an upper left square block as possible with entries 1, and partially filling the next row below that block (and, symmetrically, the next column to the right of that block) with the remaining available entries 1. The value of $f(k)$ achieved in this way is
$$
f(k)=c(k)^{c(k)} \cdot  [(c(k)+1)/c(k)]^{r(k)} \cdot [r(k)+1]
$$
where the aforementioned upper left square block has size $c(k) \times c(k)$, and $2r(k)$ is the number of residual entries 1 available to partially fill the next row and column, as described. It remains to give explicit expressions for $c(k)$ and $r(k)$. There are probably prettier and more succinct forms, but quickly one could just specify
$$
c(k)=1+\frac{k}{4}+\frac{k}{6}+\frac{k}{9}+\frac{k}{13}-\frac{k}{8}-2\left( \frac{k}{12} \right) -\frac{k}{18}
$$
where division is to be interpreted as integer division, and
$$
r(k)=k-3+(1-c(k))c(k)/2
$$
I have verified that these expressions give the correct minimal values by explicit computation of all possibilities.

An alternative expression for $c(k)$ is
$$
c(k) = \mbox{int} \left[ \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + 2k-6} \right]
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is the minimum "achieved by filling as large an upper left square block as possible with entries 1" for $k=6$? Thanks.

Comment: @EmmaT - Why are you asking these questions? My answer is valid for all $k$. For $k=6$, you have a $3\times 3$ block, and you can easily convince yourself that any relocation of entries will increase the value of the product.

Comment: Sorry that I confused the minimal configuration with another configuration for k=6, but how about $k=7$ (do you get 108 by "filling as large an upper left square block as possible with entries 1", and partially filling the next row below that block (and, symmetrically, the next column to the right of that block) with the remaining available entries 1")? Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly express $f$ by combinatorial numbers or perhaps using multinomial coefficients? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EmmaT - For $k=7$, the minimal configuration yields 72, not 108. You can do it in your head - the $\delta_{i} $ are 4,3,3,2,1,1. I don't understand what you're aiming at regarding combinatorial numbers. I've given the result as a function of $k$. If you wish, replace $k$ by the binomial coefficient $\left( k \atop 1 \right)$. One can surely obfuscate it some more such as to seem less facetious.

Comment: Now I see what you mean by "partially filling the next row below that block (and, symmetrically, the next column to the right of that block) with the remaining available entries 1 ".  As I checked for many cases the statement holds now, but what is the mathematical or rigorous reason why any other configuration will yield a larger product? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EmmaT - The reason is essentially that, for $a\geq b$, $(a+1)(b-1)<ab$, so, roughly speaking, you want to partition the $\delta_{i} $ into two sets which are maximal and minimal, respectively. The symmetry requirement correlates entries a little bit, leading to a preference for keeping as many $\delta_{i} =1$ as possible even if it means keeping the large $\delta_{i} $ smaller than 6. Note of course that the problem has symmetries w.r.t. permuting rows and columns, but the arrangement I chose is probably the simplest if you want to do inductive proofs, say.

Comment: @EmmaT - I've added an alternative expression for $c(k)$ to the answer. Shorter, but requires more than the four elementary operations of arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, but I had obtained the alternative expression by the time when the question in my earlier comment was deleted. However, how would you use your reason $(a+1)(b−1)<ab$ to explain the comparison on the configurations (5,2,2,2,2,1) and (4,3,3,2,1,1)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EmmaT - This is what I mean by the symmetry requirement correlating entries; in general, you don't get to do $(a+1)(b-1)<ab$ considerations in isolation, but you have to consider the relative merits of two such tradeoffs. In your example, you move an entry from column 5 to 3, gaining you a factor 4/3, but you simultaneously have to move an entry from column 1 to 2, losing you a factor 5/6. The merit of changing the value of a $\delta_{i} $ from 2 to 1 is always the greatest, hence my statement "keeping as many $\delta_{i} =1$ as possible".